# QGIS EPSG 3412 stereographic project doesn't work

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I've downloaded ozone maps from NASA Earth Observation site (https://neo.gsfc.nasa.gov/view.php?datasetId=AURA_OZONE_M&year=2019),

[image: Original image from the website EPSG 4326]  it's in EPSG 4326 - WGS 84, and I would like to project it centered on Antarctica, so on EPSG 3412.
But when I change it on the Layer SR option, it doesnt' work. I don't get a map centered over South Pole but just a blue line like on the image below
[image: Stereographic projection].

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try re-projecting to 102037.

Comment: Just to complete the previous comment, you should **never** "change the Layer SR option". You must **reproject** the original raster to your desired projection.